# using to 2 selects to automatically determine what is selected on a third

Tags: javascript

I suspect you would need to use javascript to do this, I have three selects

```
<select id="Sides">
<option value="Single">Single</option>
<option value="Double">Double</option>
</select>

<select id="Delivery">
<option value="Standard">Standard</option>
<option value="Express">Express</option>
</select>

<select id="SidesDelivery">
<option value="SingleStandard">Single Standard</option>
<option value="SingleExpress">Single Express</option>
<option value="DoubleStandard">Single Standard</option>
<option value="DoubleExpress">Single Express</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to know how if you choose Single in sides and Standard in delivery how to automatically select SingleStandard in SidesDelivery

I think it would work something like this

```
OnChange if Sides select== Single && Delivery select== Single
then sidesdelivery= SingleStandard
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get much better help on StackOverflow if you show code that you tried that doesn't work than merely asking how to do something. Did you use on change events and they didn't work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ben1989/79uxp/   tried that and something else that didn't work but didn't have a jsfiddle account an lost what I had done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution,

```
$('#Sides,#Delivery').change(function(){
    var one,two;
    if(this.id=="Sides"){
         one = $('#'+this.id).val();
         two= $('#Delivery').val();
    }
    if(this.id=="Delivery"){
        two = $('#'+this.id).val();
        one= $('#Sides').val();
    }

    $('#SidesDelivery > option').each(function(index,obj){

        if($(obj).text().split(" ")[0]== one && $(obj).text().split(" ")[1]==two){
            $(this).prop('selected','selected');
        }

    });


});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6CgLu/1/)**

Comment: Could you explain how                               $('#SidesDelivery > option').each(function(index,obj){

        if($(obj).text().split(" ")[0]== one && $(obj).text().split(" ")[1]==two){
            $(this).prop('selected','selected');
        } 

Works I understand the rest of it?

Comment: Here jquery each loop iterating each option of drop-down. the code $(obj).text() gets the value like "Single Standard" now I split this so it returns an array having two elements (say ["Single","Standard"] here )  then we have implemented if condition saying $(obj).text().split(" ")[0] will result to "Single" here and $(obj).text().split(" ")[1] will be "Standard" and which is separately assigned in variables "one" and "two" ....so having condition satisfied we just make selected that option using $(this).prop('selected','selected');....hoping that it is clear to you now, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
var a = document.getElementById('Sides').value;
var b = document.getElementById('Delivery').value;

document.getElementById('SidesDelivery').value = a+b ;
```